# How to revert part of changes in the previous commit

Tags: git

In the previous `git commit`, I add a new file (lets call it C) and make some changes to file A and file B.

Is there a way to remove file C and also revert the change made to file A by `git commit --amend`?

Comment: Do you want to rewrite history or not? (i.e. remove those changes from the repo entirely, or simply revert them?) [Gavin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58867180/4518341) covers the latter.

Comment: If you didn't push the changes I would use it `git gui` to amend the command and remove the file. Select amend and unstage both files. Commit. Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you mostly want to revert the commit but keep changes to one file.

First, do a git revert but leave the changes staged:

`git revert -n HEAD`

Then unstage changes you don't want reverted (file B)

`git reset HEAD -- B`

And discard unstaged changes:

`git checkout -- .`

This should leave staged changes to revert changes to files A and C. Then you can commit as you wish (new commit or amending previous commit if it hasn't yet been pushed elsewhere).

[git revert docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert)

Answer (score 1):

## If not pushed

You can reset to the previous commit and attempt to do what you really intended again.

```
git reset HEAD~1
git add A B
git commit ...
```

## If pushed

Since you're asking about `git commit --amend` I assumed the changes are local only. If the changes are already in the remote repo (aka pushed) then it may be better to remove `C` in a separate commit.

```
git rm C 
git commit -m "Removing C"
```